# regex matching pair of brackets

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to write a Sublime Text 2 syntax highlighter for Simulink's *Target Language Compiler* (TLC) files. This is a scripting language for auto-generating code. In TLC, the syntax to expand the contents of a token (similar to dereferencing a pointer in C or C++) is

```
%<token>
```

The regular expression I wrote to match this is

```
%<.+?>
```

This works for most cases, but fails for the following statement

```
%<LibAddToCommonIncludes("<string.h>")>
```

Modifying the regular expression to greedy fixes this if the statement is by itself on a line, but fails in several other cases. So that is not an option.

For that line, the highlighting stops at the first `>` instead of the second. How can I modify the regular expression to handle this case?

It'd be great if there was a general expression that could handle any number of nested `<>` pairs; for example

```
%<...<...>...<...<...>...>...>
```

where the dots are optional characters. The entire expression above should be a single match.

Comment: I don't know anything about writing the syntax highlighter, but have you looked at other languages? There must be code to perform bracket matching. http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html

Comment: Do you need to write a regex fragment that matches a string and its contents, so that the nested angle brackets are treated as part of the string?  That might be as crude as `([^"]|"[^"]*")*`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Updated the question. I definitely don't want it to be dependent on there being a string somewhere, the regex should just skip nested `<>` pairs.

Comment: What I asked was slightly different.  If there is a string, do you want to ignore the contents of the string altogether (specifically, to ignore angle brackets in it)?  The pattern I quoted would more or less work (it doesn't accommodate backslash-double quote escapes in strings) to gobble up `"<string.h>"` as a single unit, thus not letting the angle brackets be 'seen' by the larger regex.  If you're not confident that where you have one double quote you'll always have pairs, then this is not the solution for you.  But if double quotes can only appear around strings, it might work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, I see. I did misunderstand what you were asking. Unfortunately, the nested `<>` pair can appear outside of strings, so that doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, I think you're running out of bounds of what a pure regex can do.  You may have to have the review what the regular expression finds before you do the substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic way through regular expressions is difficult -as explained very well in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).

You can try to specifically match 2 `<` characters through a regex. Something like `%<.+?<.+?>.+?>`.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but great explanation in the linked answer as to why what I want may not be possible.